# Application of Jensen's Inequality for convex functions

Tags: probability

In the handouts for my course, quoted (without proof) is the following equality

$$ \Big \langle \exp \left( \sum_{i}a_i x \right) \Big\rangle = \exp \left(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}a_i a_j \langle x^2 \rangle \right) $$

I have been thingking along the lines of [Jensen's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) and think it should be an inequlaity between the left and right hand sides. $x$ is a gaussian random variable with zero mean. But I am unable to prove the equality?

Can someone supply a proof for the equality (or correct inequality)?

Answer (score 0):

A well known fact is $Ee^{tX} =e^{t^{2}\sigma^{2}/2}$ if $X$ is normal with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^{2}=EX^{2}$. Just put $t=\sum a_k$ and expand $t^{2}$ as $\sum_{i,j} a_ia_j$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Does this result have a name, that I can look up/cite?

Comment: @jcp Just look for 'moment generating functions'. You will most certainly see this as one of the examples.

Comment: Oh well I guess it is trivial to prove, $E[\exp(tx)] = \int \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2})\exp(tx)dx$?

Comment: @jcp Right. All you have to do is to write $x^{2}-2\sigma^{2}tx$ as $(x-\sigma^{2}t)^{2} +\sigma^{4}t^{2}$ and make the change of variable $y=x-\sigma^{2}t$.

Comment: or complete the square